# How to findViewById form another XML file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I connent an addevent.java with addevent.xml is content a listview, the listview take its element from another XML file "item.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/d"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:drawablePadding="0dip"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/en"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/d" >
        </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

now I need to findviewbyId not from basic xml file but form another "item.xml"

I tried **LayoutInflater** as this, code but it isn't work:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addevent);
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyList);
        myList.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();

        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        tvDisplayDate = (EditText)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.editd);
        btnChangeDate=(Button)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.d);
```

any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From insinde your `MyAdapter` class you can override the `getView` method (that's the one that produces the item renderers on demand).

After recycling / inflating the proper layout for the current item (say `convertView`), you can access all of its children using the `findViewById` method called on the `convertView`:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // initialize, inflate convertView from your layout if needed; 
        tvDisplayDate = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editd);
        // populate convertView with the item's details
    }
```

Comment: @Akashkumar see the edited response with the full method signature: `convertView` is the second parameter of the `getView` method inside the `Adapter` implementation;

Comment: I just spent an hour resolving this error. The only thing I missed was calling findViewById on convertView. Thanks for making me realize this!

Answer (score 6):

Try this `View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.item, null);`

How you can see, static from() method takes 1 argument(Context) and you obtains LayoutInflater from given Context, in your case it will be your Activity where you want to inflate View.

Hope it helps!